# Verilog: Cannot Attach Register As Output?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to compile my module and it works fine when I remove the badData register from the testbench. However, the moment I add it, verilog complains "Error loading design".

Module Code:

```
module hamming_code #( parameter TOTAL_LENGTH = 15,
                               parameter PARITY_BITS = 4
                           )
                (
                    //inputs
                    input [TOTAL_LENGTH-1:0] codeword,

                    //outputs
                    output [TOTAL_LENGTH-1:0] correctedWord,
                output reg badData
                );
```

Testbench code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module tb ();
integer pass_count, fail_count;
reg clock;
reg [14:0] cw; 
wire [14:0] ccw;
reg error;
integer i;

hamming_code uut (// Inputs 
                            .codeword(cw),
                            // Outputs
                            .correctedWord(ccw),
                            .badData(error)

                         );

initial begin
// initial values
clock <= 0;
pass_count <= 0;
fail_count <= 0;
error <= 0;
wait(0);
end

always@(*)
#5 clock <= ~clock;

endmodule
```

Comment: Are you removing the trailing comma as well? Could you post failing and working versions and include actual error you are getting.

Comment: I have moved the code to pastebin because it is a bit long: http://pastebin.com/u9w5Ef8Y

This is the version that fails.

Comment: I have copied it to [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Xim), but looks like the same version posted in the question. compiles ok there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BadData` is an output from your `uut`. 
It should be connected to a `wire` in the TB. Also it shouldn't be assigned any value in TB (you are assigning a 0).

When you remove `reg error`, Its automatically inferred as  a `wire`. that's why there is no error.